# Xamarin.Android SQLiteConnection cannot open database file

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android, sqlite-net

I want to open or create (if not exists) a database file, but when I try to create a new instance of the SQLiteConnection class, It's throwing an Exception with the error code 30 (misuse) amd cannot open the database file.

Here is my code:

```
class DatabaseOpen
{
    protected SQLiteConnection db;
    ... // Here are another attributes of the class, which is not relevant to the database connection.
    public DatabaseOpen(String filename="noNameFree") // String filename = "noNameFree"
    {
        String dbPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        dbPath = Path.Combine(dbPath, filename+".db3");
        Java.IO.File dbFile = Application.Context.GetDatabasePath(dbPath);
        dbFile.Mkdirs();
        var dbObject = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
        db = dbObject;
    }
    ... // Here are the other methods of the class which is not relevant to the database connection.
}
```

In the code above the `dbPath` variable is setted to the following path:

```
/data/data/<AppName>.<AppName>/files/noNameFree.db3
```

I don't see what I writed wrong. I hope somebody see the problem with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I moved my application from the SD card to the internal storage and then it's get working. After that I moved it back to my SD card and it's still working. I think at the deployment Visual Studio isn't installed it to the right place.

Note:
I think the SQLite.Net won't throw a MISUSE Exception in this case. I will create an issue about this to the developers.